# TypeError when submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error of:

```
 TypeError: val.replace is not a function
```

which is showing the main *jquery.js* file and cannot seem to trace the problem. I have stripped my code down to the bare essentials to try to isolate the problem, but to no avail. What I have done is to just `alert(data)` in the code, but this does not fire. Instead, the form seems to resubmit and in my post tab in firebug, there are 2 submit events. I would be grateful if someone could suggest a way to troubleshoot this.

I would like to add that the validation is working ok, but when it comes to the submit handler, this is where the problem is.

Many thanks

JS

```
$(function() {

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorClass: 'form_error',
        errorElement: 'span',
        ignore: ":hidden:not(select)",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.siblings('span'));
        }
    });

    $("#USRboxrtv").validate({
        rules: {
            requested: {
                required: true
            },
            service: {
                required: true
            },
            rtvdept: {
                required: true
            },
            address2: {
                required: true
            },
            box_rtv: {
                required: true
            }

        },
        messages: {
            requested: {
                required: '* required: You must enter your name'
            },
            rtvdept: {
                required: "* required: You must select a department"
            },
            address2: {
                required: "* required: You must select a customer address"
            },
            service: {
                required: "* required: You must select a service level"
            },
            box_rtv: {
                required: "* required: You must enter a box for retrieval"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function() {

            if ($("#USRboxrtv").valid() === true) {
                var data = $("#USRboxrtv").serialize();
                alert(data);

            }
        }

    });
});
```

html input

```
   <p>

    <input name="submit" class="usersubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input name="formreset" class="usercancel" type="reset" />

   </p>
```

Comment: please create jsfiddle of your test case

Comment: I have tried to create test case, but fiddle just throws shell error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the error message is due to this line`var data = $("#USRboxrtv").serialize();` . I can't tell you what's the reason for it, but if you [search this error on google](https://www.google.co.in/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1LENP_enIN492IN492&es_sm=122&q=%7B%20name%3a%20elem.name,%20value%3a%20val.replace%28%20CRLF,%20%22%5Cr%5Cn%22%20%29%20%7D&spell=1&sa=X&ei=LsVkU7ycEcm9ugTKnICgBA&ved=0CCYQBSgA&biw=1920&bih=957) , you will find that the error is in the serialize function. Make sure that the necessary conditions are met for serialize to work. You have not provided the HTML for `$("#USRboxrtv")`, so I am not sure where is the error in this case. By the way, are you using the latest version of jquery?

val will either return a string or undefined. I think in your case, val is undefined and that's because you are getting this error.

And as you commented in one of the post :

`$(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");`

In this code you are actually assigning an empty value to `$(".chosen-select")` which is causing this error.

Comment: No, then the val is undefined

Comment: There is val function anywhere else. Where is it coming from? Thanks

Comment: Creating a fiddle for it will be better.

Comment: This line in jquery is returned as the error: return { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( rCRLF, "\r\n" ) };